# HTML table not rendering as expected

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a HTML email, and therefore using a lot of nested tables. However, My second `<tr>` is not inline with the first row, and I'm not quite sure why. Here is how it's coming out at the moment:
[image]

I want the second row to be centred rather than touching the edges.

Here's what I have:

```html
  <!-- BACKGROUND -->
  <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%" bgcolor="#000000">
   <tbody>
    <tr>
     <td>
      <!-- SECTION 1 -->
      <!--START OF EMAIL BODY -->
      <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="600" align="center">
       <tbody>
        <tr>
         <td>
          <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="600" bgcolor="#ffffff">
           <tbody>
            <tr>
             <td height="30"><!-- PADDING --></td>
             <tr>
              <td style="font-family:Arial;font-size:12px;line-height:15px;color:#353535;text-align:center;">
              Not rendering correctly? View this email as a web page <a href="#" target="_blank" style="color:#54537e;">here</a>.
              </td>
             </tr>
             <tr>
              <td height="15"><!-- PADDING --></td>
             </tr>
            </tr>
           </tbody>
          </table>
         </td>
        </tr>
       </tbody>
      </table>
      <!--END OF EMAIL BODY -->
      <!-- SECTION 1 END -->
     </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>
      <!--  SECTION 2 -->
      <!-- LOGO AND SOCIAL MEDIA -->
      <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="600" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"> 
       <tbody>
        <tr>
         <td><!-- <td height="60">-->
          <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
           <tbody>
            <tr>
             <td width="425"><!-- PADDING --></td>
             <td style="font-family:Arial;font-size:10px;line-height:15px;color:#353535;text-align:center;font-weight:bold;">SHARE
                                                    </td>
             <td width="10"><!-- PADDING (SPACE BETWEEN SHARE AND LINKS) --></td>
             <!-- LINKEDIN-->
             <td>
             </td>
             <!-- TWITTER -->
             <td>
            </td> 
             <!-- YOUTUBE -->
             <td>
            </td>
            </tr>
           </tbody>
          </table>
          <!-- SECTION 2 END -->
         </td>

    </tr>
   </tbody>
  </table>
```

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it). Questions that depend on external resources to be understood become useless when the external resource goes away or is fixed. Create a [MCVE] and put it in **the question itself** instead.

Comment: Don't confuse a row with the contents of a row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with the alignment of the **row**.

What are misaligned are the two tables **inside** the rows.

Compare:

> ```
> <!--START OF EMAIL BODY -->
> <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="600" align="center">
> <!-- LOGO AND SOCIAL MEDIA -->
> <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="600" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
> ```

One of them is centred. The other is left aligned.